# awk command works, but not in openwrt's awk

Tags: awk

Works here: 'awk.js.org/`
but not in openwrt's awk, which returns the error message:

> `awk: bad regex '^(server=|address=)[': Missing ']'`

Hello everyone!
I'm trying to use an awk command I wrote which is:

> `'!/^(server=|address=)[/][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-.]+([/]|[/]#)$|^#|^\s*$/ {count++}; END {print count+0}'`

Which counts invalid lines in a dns blocklist (oisd in this case):

Input would be eg:

```
server=/0--foodwarez.da.ru/anyaddress.1.1.1
serverspellerror=/0-000.store/
server=/0-24bpautomentes.hu/
server=/0-29.com/
server=/0-day.us/
server=/0.0.0remote.cryptopool.eu/
server=/0.0mail6.xmrminingpro.com/
server=/0.0xun.cryptopool.space/
```

Output for this should be "2" since there are two lines that don't match the criteria (correctly formed address, comments, or blank lines).

I've tried formatting the command every which way with [], but can't find anything that works.  Does anyone have an idea what format/syntax/option needs adjusting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To portably include `-` in a bracket expression it has to be the first or last character, otherwise it means a range, and `\s` is shorthand for `[[:space:]]` in only some awks. This will work in any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '!/^(server=|address=)[/][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:].-]+([/]|[/]#)$|^#|^[[:space:]]*$/ {count++}; END {print count+0}' file
2
```

Per @tripleee's comment below if your awk is broken such that a `/` inside a bracket expression isn't treated as literal then you may need this instead:

```
$ awk '!/^(server=|address=)\/[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:].-]+(\/|\/#)$|^#|^[[:space:]]*$/ {count++}; END {print count+0}' file
2
```

but get a new awk, e.g. GNU awk, as who knows what other surprises the one you're using may have in store for you!

Comment: You'll still have to backslash the literal slashes.

Comment: @tripleee The slashes are inside bracket expressions so they're already literal, you don't need to escape them too. You need either `[/]` or `\/`, not both.

Comment: My impression of the OP's error message is that their Awk doesn't obey this convention. I'm guessing it's Busybox underneath.

Comment: @tripleee I haven't heard of any awk being broken in that way but if you're right (and the error message `awk: bad regex '^(server=|address=)[': Missing ']'` does seem to suggest that) then I guess the OP could try replacing each `[/]` with `\/`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hello everyone, there are two options that worked here!
Using /\ instead of [/] works with OpenWRT's included awk.  And I found gawk (GNU awk?) in OpenWRT, which works with the [/] syntax.  I think I'll switch to using gawk in this instance since it seems to conform either way. 
Can't thank everyone enough, and for how fast the help was also.  Good learning experience for me in (g)awk....

Answer (score 0):

```
'!/^(server=|address=)[/][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-.]+([/]|[/]#)$|^#|^\s*$/ {count++}; END {print count+0}'
```

`-` has special meaning inside `[` and `]`, it is used to denote range e.g. `[A-Z]` means uppercase ASCII letter, use `\` escape sequence to make it literal dash, let `file.txt` content be

```
server=/0--foodwarez.da.ru/anyaddress.1.1.1
serverspellerror=/0-000.store/
server=/0-24bpautomentes.hu/
server=/0-29.com/
server=/0-day.us/
server=/0.0.0remote.cryptopool.eu/
server=/0.0mail6.xmrminingpro.com/
server=/0.0xun.cryptopool.space/
```

then

```
awk '!/^(server=|address=)[/][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]\-.]+([/]|[/]#)$|^#|^\s*$/ {count++}; END {print count+0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2
```

You might also consider replacing `\s` using `[[:space:]]` in order to main consistency.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Hello Daweo, thankyou very much for the reply.  I updated to both of your suggestions, and they both make sense.  I'm still getting the same error:
awk: bad regex '^(server=|address=)[': Missing ']'
just running awk with no options is returning:
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-10-14 22:44:41 UTC) multi-call binary.
Is it possible this is just a limited version of awk?

Comment: @Wizballs : try replacing every instance of `[/]` (the ones in the middle of the regex not the bookends) with `[\/]` or simply `\/` and see if that works

Comment: Putting a backslash in front of `-` in a bracket expression isn't portable, nor is `\s`, so YMMV with both of those depending on which awk version you're using.